# HttpPost on ASP.Net MVC3 - "No parameterless constructor defined for this object"

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [ASP.NET MVC: No parameterless constructor defined for this object](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1355464/asp-net-mvc-no-parameterless-constructor-defined-for-this-object)

I'm working on an ASP.NET MVC3 application.

I'm trying to use the `[HttpPost]` to retrieve information when a user enters it on a form.

Basing what I do off the "default" blank ASP.Net project's Logon scripts, I have the following:

In my controller:

```
    public ActionResult Ticket(int id)
    {
        Models.Ticket model = new Models.Ticket(id);
        return View("Ticket", model);
    }

    [HttpPost]
    public ActionResult Ticket(int id, MMCR.Models.Ticket model)
    {
        if (id != model.TicketNo)
        {
            return View("Error");
        }
        return View("Ticket", model);
    }
```

And in the View I have:

```
@using (Html.BeginForm()) {
    <div>
    <fieldset>
    <legend>View Ticket Details</legend>

    <div class="editor-label">
        @Html.LabelFor(m=>m.Status)    
    </div>
    <div class="editor-field">
        @Html.DropDownListFor(m=>m.Status, Model.Status)
    </div>

    <p>
        <input type="submit" value="Update" />
    </p>

    </fieldset>
    </div>
}
```

(obviously snipping out repetetive stuff).

However, when I click on the button I get an error:

> Exception Details: System.MissingMethodException: No parameterless constructor defined for this object.

Can anyone give some advice on how to resolve this?

Comment: Which object is missing the parameterless constructor?  If it's one of yours, you can take a stab in the dark and add a parameterless constructor to it.

Comment: None of the stuff in the Stack Trace is from one of my classes. :(

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/q/1355464/102937

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/q/3477518/102937

Comment: does `MMCR.Models.Ticket` have a no-args ctor?

Answer (score 18, accepted):

Your class `MMCR.Models.Ticket` needs a parameterless constructor.

When you pass an object of this type through the Post method, MVC will create an instance of the class using a parameterless constructor. It will then map the form fields to that object.

Comment: so any information in the model that's not in the form is lost in the new model?

Comment: That is correct. If you have information you want to keep, you should add it to the view through Html.HiddenFor(x=>x.PropertyToKeep). That will insure it is populated when the form posts.

Comment: But... I've got that are just displayed as Labels that aren't being transfered over. :/

Comment: Labels don't get transfered because they aren't considered to be HTML controls. Only HTML controls are included; that's why you have to do a HiddenFor to get a value back if you don't have the property in another control.